# Can you configure a Wordpress-based site for private use only?

Tags: security, wordpress

If I build a site using Wordpress, is there a straightforward way to restrict access to the whole site to only those who I specify?

I've looked a few plugins that attempt to redirect unregistered users to the login page, but most seem old, fragile, or generally just hacks.

I want to know if a standard Wordpress installation lets you do this, or otherwise if there's a decent and secure plugin to do it. I need a solution that doesn't involve changing the default wordpress PHP scripts as I don't have direct access to the server. It's quite important that the solution is secure.

Any help or past experience would be appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies if this is better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, wasn't aware this existed. Please move if necessary :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of WP, I believe v 3.1.2, has this option for pages and posts under the quick edit.

You can set a password per post / page or mark them as private.